# Kubernetes Replicas | Not distributing resource load equally

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Python Application in Pod `Foo`. This has 5 replicas foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, foo_4, foo_5.

Each Replica has been assigned resources (in Kubernetes)

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 1500m
    memory: 1600Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 1200Mi
```

After the application is successfully deployed, I am using a Load Testing Library to simulate load, which again works fine BUT the load is not distributed equally.

```
kubectl top pods
foo-1   1273m         489Mi           
foo-2    279m         373Mi           
foo-3    283m         365Mi           
foo-4    268m         363Mi           
foo-5    280m         374Mi
```

Is there any configuration to make sure CPU load is divided equally amoung all Pods-replicas?

---

How are the requests sent:

- Step 1. Ingress LoadBalancer (with external IP). Ingress if from https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/download/ingress-nginx-2.5.0/ingress-nginx-2.5.0.tgz
- Step 2. NGINX Server (djnago-uwsgi-nginx stack)
- Step 3. Djnago Server is hit where the processing is done

Comment: can you attach the YAMLs that you have used in order to deploy this?. Edit and attach your YAMLs?.

Comment: nothing extra in yaml, `resources` section i already added to post

Comment: Is there a service through which you are sending the load  or directly using pod ip?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu, I have updated the post for the request cycle. Ingress > NGINX-UWSGI > Djnago

Comment: Hello, can you tell which `Ingress` controller are you using? Is your Kubernetes cluster on prem or is it a cloud solution?

Comment: Ingress is https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/download/ingress-nginx-2.5.0/ingress-nginx-2.5.0.tgz

Comment: I even tried without Ingress, and same issue is there

Comment: the cluster is running on GKE

Comment: As there could be a multiple reasons why this setup behaves like you are telling, have you tried to run your setup in a 1 node cluster? Could you provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your app and tell how you are testing it?